# Rng initialization in main.c or in source.c?

Tags: c, header, srand

I have several header and source files that I needed to create, in which there are functions that generate random numbers. If I wanted to initialize my rng,  where do I have to put my "srand(time(NULL))" line, in my code? Is it ok to put it in my main.c file? Does it affect the other source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put it in the main file. Once you call `srand` it is applicable for the entire program, even if it has multiple files.